# Dose jxbrowser hava the time plan to support Java Platform Module System?

Tags: jxbrowser

Dose jxbrowser hava the time plan to support Java Platform Module System ?

I hava already update my java project use module after JDK9,but I cannot migrate the jxbrowser to the module project.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment JxBrowser doesn't support Java Platform Module System because it uses the internal APIs that aren't exported from Java modules. Once we find alternatives and get rid of using the internal APIs, we will support Java Platform Module System.

Comment: If I just “add exports” as this https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000046846 said,could I run JxBrowser in Module System?Thank you for your reply.

Comment: We did not test this approach from our side, however it may work for you.